# Camunda - why does generated form not appear?

Tags: bpmn, camunda, camunda-modeler

I have created a form for a message start event and a user task. I can see in the generated XML something that looks like:

```
<bpmn:extensionElements>
  <camunda:formData>
    <camunda:formField id="myField" label="My field" type="string" />
  </camunda:formData>
```

etc etc....

So it looks like the XML should be defining a generated form for me.

However, when I go to Camunda and try and create a task from the message start event form instead of seeing the HTML form I am expecting, I get a message saying:

```
This task contains an external form to complete it.  In order to open the external form click on the "Open external form" link below.
```

When I click on the link for the form, I get a 404 error.  The link it is trying to reach is `/camunda/app/tasklist/default/MyMessageFormKey`. `default` is the name of the `process-engine` xml field in the `processes.xml` file.  The directory `default` doesn't exist in the path, so should this value be something else?

Is there something I need to do when creating the Maven pom file that builds the task?

Comment: Please post the XML snippet of the entire `userTask` activity and the `startEvent` event.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't, it's on a system that doesn't have internet access.  However, I have not amended anything by hand; it's all auto-generated by modeller.

Comment: Do you have a formkey "MyMessageFormKey" defined in the model?

Answer (score 3):

You probably have written something in "form key" field. That is used for accessing external forms, but you need Camunda to generate form for you using your form fields. Clear the "form key" field, check the XML if it's all okay, and that should be it.